# Google Sheets =REGEXEXTRACT

Tags: google-sheets-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyiFX.png)

Good afternoon
Please tell me how to fix =REGEXEXTRACT
date 25-26.01.2023 so that it selects data on 26.01.2023 and when pulling, the data does not go astray.

Comment: If there’s a date range, are you looking to grab the first date or the second? Your example desired output for the first two rows is not consistent.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want the last date in the date range try:

```
=RIGHT(A1,10)
```

If you always want the first date if there’s a range try:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=10,
      RIGHT(A1,10),
      LEFT(A1,2)&RIGHT(A1,8)
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Happy to help! Mind marking my answer as accepted & upvoting?